# Migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, magento-community, sql, zend-framework

I have this problem,by migrating magento 1 to magento 2.

What i'm doing wrong?

```
php bin/magento migrate:data --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.3.1/config.xml     
Reset the current position of migration to start from the beginning



  [Zend_Db_Statement_Exception]                                                                                                                                     
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'angoloj4_amboim.eav_attribute_set' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `eav_attribute_set`  






  [PDOException]                                                                                               
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'angoloj4_amboim.eav_attribute_set' doesn't exist  



migrate:data [-r|--reset] config
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to migrate **Magento-1** to **Magento-2**, before migrating please take **back-up of your data**.

After that run the following commands:

> bin/magento migrate:settings
>
> bin/magento migrate:data
>
> bin/magento migrate:delta

Answer (score -1):

For Magento 1 to Magento 2 migration you can follow this below process

**Install Magento 2 Data Migration Tool via Composer**
You can install the Data Migration tool into a fresh Magento 2 store using Composer. Remember, it’s not a Magento 2 extension, it’s a standalone shell application that requires Magento 2 store to become operational.

To install the Data Migration Tool, make sure that the version of Magento 2 store and Data Migration Tool match.

For example, if you are using Magento version 2.2.0, you must install the Data Migration Tool version 2.2.0. In general, If you are using the latest version of Magento 2 platform, you have to use the most recent version of the Data Migration Tool as well.

To find the version of your store, navigate to the root directory of your Magento 2 via SSH and enter the following command:

```
php bin/magento --version
```

Now, once you know the version of your Magento 2 store, it’s the time to install the Magento 2 Data Migration Tool.

Keep in mind that you must update the location of the Data Migration Tool package in the composer.json file to make it work.

To do that, just run the following commands:

```
composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com

composer require magento/data-migration-tool:<version>
```

In the above CLI command,  refers to the version of the Data Migration Tool that must match the Magento 2 version discovered earlier.

For example, if you are using Magento version 2.2.0, enter:

```
composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com

composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.2.0
```

You will be asked to enter your developer authentication keys. Go to the Magento Marketplace. Sign in using your login credentials, go to your profile and then click Access Keys under My Products section.

If you already have keys then, your public key will be your username and the private key will be your password. Otherwise, create a new key pair by clicking the Create a New Access Key button.

In a few seconds, the Data Migration Tool will be successfully installed on your Magento 2 store.

**Configure Magento 2 Data Migration Tool**
After the installation is finished, the following directories will contain mapping and configuration files for the Data Migration Tool.

```
<Magento 2 root dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource
```

The above file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Open Source platform to Magento 2 Open Source platform.

The above file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Commerce to Magento 2 Commerce.

Before you migrate any settings and data, you must create a config.xml file in the relevant directory. For example, if you are performing data migration from Magento 1 Open Source platform to Magento 2 Open Source platform, navigate to the

```
<Magento 2 root dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/<Magento 1.x version> directory and rename config.xml.dist to config.xml.
```

Next, open config.xml in your favorite code editor and specify the following:

```
</source>

<destination>

<database host="localhost" name="Magento2-DB-name" user="DB-username" password="DB-password"/>

</destination>

<options>

<crypt_key>Magento1-Encrypted-Key</crypt_key>

</options>
```

In the above code,  has the database information of Magento 1 and  has the relevant database information of Magento 2.  is mandatory and needs to be filled prior run. It is the encryption key of Magento 1 store and can be found in the /app/etc/local.xml file, within the  tag.

When finished, save the config.xml and you are done.

**Migrate Settings Using Magento 2 Data Migration Tool**

Here is how you can use the Data Migration Tool to migrate settings from Magento 1 to Magento 2. These settings include stores, websites, system configurations such as shipping, payment, tax settings, etc.

According to the Magento Data Migration Order, you should migrate settings first. To start migrating the settings, navigate to your Magento 2 root directory via SSH terminal and run the following command:

```
php bin/magento migrate:settings --reset <path to your config.xml>
```

where  this would be vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource//config.xml. I have used --reset argument in the above command which forces the Data Migration Tool to start from the beginning.

Once the settings migration is over, a successful message will be displayed.

**Migrate Data Using Magento 2 Data Migration Tool**
Data migration from Magento 1 platform to Magento 2 platform includes products, categories, orders, customers, wish lists, ratings, etc. To migrate data, run the following CLI command:

```
php bin/magento migrate:data --reset <path to your config.xml>
```

As this command runs, the Magento 2 Data Migration Tool saves its current progress, and in the case of an error, stop the process and resume from the last known good state. Also, the Magento 2 Data Migration Tool may report some errors during the migration. In such a case, refer to the Troubleshooting page of the Magento 2 Data Migration Tool for further assistance.

Once the data migration is complete, you will receive a success message.